# libQGLViewer-2.7.2 qmake opengl

Tags: qmake, qglviewer

I'm trying to compile libQGLViewer-2.7.2
on linux amd64 debian qt5
using qmake, I got

Project ERROR: Could not find feature opengles2.

Any idea what's wrong? how can I debug this?
rhanks

Comment: Debian 10 - 11 - 12 no "opengles2 issues" when doing `$ cd libQGLViewer-2.7.2/ && qmake` . However, a "disable-designer-plugin.patch" is required if you want to create a valid Makefile with qmake https://drive.google.com/file/d/18VRCh32yjquEb3fZ4lvxXo2AUA_QXWTG/view?usp=sharing